# How to populate form after validation fails using custom formRequest class in laravel

Tags: laravel, forms, validation, laravel-formrequest

I am using Custom ForRequest class to validate my form, it works fine. But when it redirects back on form page, the form is not populated.
I don't want to use

```
old('form_field_name')
```

My code will be weird if I use old('form_field_name') because I use same form to store and to update the model 
What am I missing? 
thanks

Comment: Are you adding old('form_field_name') for input values?

Comment: @CanCelik no, I don't add it. But I have already used validation directly in controller and I used redirect()-.back()->withInput(). Is there any way to do same with Cutom FormRquest? My code will be weird if I use  old('form_field_name') because I use same form to store and to update the model

Comment: Provide your form code. old() method is the way you get the values you passed back with ->withInput();

Answer (score 0):

if you use the same form for store and update, use `old` with `optional`. just like

```
<input name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('name', optional($object)->name) }}">
```

this is the way you can get the old form values as well as the object values. if there is old value it will put that as value otherwise it will put the object value as value.

> make sure to send the object as null from the create function.